# How can I split a MultyPolygon in JTS into Polygons?

Tags: geotools, jts

I am using JTS and I have one big Multypolygon with seperated Areas. How can I get a List of Polygons representing these seperated areas.

Thanks in Advance
Lukas

Comment: What have you tried so far? Basically, you loop through the individual polygons in the multi polygons and put them in a list or other collection

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly simple, given a MultiPolygon `p`:

```
ArrayList<Polygon> polygons = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < p.getNumGeometries(); i++) {
    Polygon polygon = (Polygon)p.getGeometryN(i);
    polygons.add(polygon)
}
```

Comment: Hey Ian,

thank you so much. I had a different solution that took so long. Now its working much better.

Best regards

Comment: Please take the [tour] to see how to become a good citizen on this site - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47962/what-should-i-do-when-the-correct-answer-to-a-question-changes-over-time